# Fractals by Fractional Integration

Tags: fractals, fractional-calculus

Since the *n*th order integral finds the volume enclosed by an *n* dimensional function, does that imply that fractional order integrals can be used to find the volume enclosed by rational (or irrational) dimensional functions, such as fractals?

I suppose that a problem with this definition is that fractals are not characterised by continuous functions and are usually just defined by recurrence relations. So are there any special cases where the fractional order integrals can be used to find the area of certain fractals?

Comment: (1) There are a couple of different ways of constructing a "fractional calculus"---what construction do you have in mind?  (2) There is not a widely agreed upon definition of what a "fractal" is, but (statistical) self-similarity is not necessarily part of that definition---self-similar sets are some of the *easiest* fractal sets to study, but they are by no means the norm in the world of fractals, (3) many fractals *are* continuous paths, e.g. the von Koch curve---the problem with fractals is that they tend not to be differentiable.

Comment: (4) Do you know anything about measure theory?  The "usual" approach to describing the "volume" or "length" or measure of a fractal is to integrate with respect to the appropriate Hausdorff measure.